# square API setup asp.net

Tags: asp.net, square-connect

I'm new to the API setup stuff. I'm trying to add payment link to a site and then they just fill out the form and click submit. I have followed the directions on https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/getting-started/ but get stuck on step 4. I have even copied their code for the payment on this stie https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/adding-payment-form/ and get the right results they say. But not sure where to go from there. The site is hosted on azure. I just don't know if I have to go to VS 2015 and create new webapi, and setup a new api in azure. I also don't know where to put the token ect from squareup. Would love anyone's help.

Thanks,

Steve

Comment: Have you looked into [Square Checkout](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/square-checkout-overview/)? It might be an easier way for you to accept payments.

Comment: I haven't actually checked into it. I'll look at it though. I am just looking for something basic.

Comment: yeah I just looked into it. seems like it's what I'm trying to do. I just don't get where I need to put the code and what code I need.

Comment: Maybe a pre-made solution like wix or bigcommerce would be better? What kind of code have you tried?

Comment: yeah I just bigcommerce and I don't get how to set any of that up. I'm wondering if I should just try wix. I'm just looking for like lables and text boxes for name, card number, cvv, expiration date, postal code and then a pay now button. Once they click the pay button boom. I just don't know where to start or what to really do. I have a basic html but not sure what I need to do with API and if I should create a new site for payments and add ssl on it? Does wix let you purchase website? Currently I'm using godaddy for the website. I wonder if I could buy one from godaddy an import it on wix.

Comment: You should try out wix or one of the other partners that integrate with Square. It sounds like getting the programming right for your situation might be tricky for you.

Comment: yeah just looked into wix and they don't offer just a basic payment option. They want you to do the whole store.